# How to get user_id from page scope id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to get page scope id (PSID) from user_id

As I know, one user have two kind ID: one for Graph API Platform (GID) and one for Messenger platform (MID).

(PSID = MID, user_id = GID)

I've found out the way to change from GID to MID:

```
GET /{GID}/ids_for_pages?access_token=[page_access_token]&appsecret_proof=[appsecret_proof]

enter code here
```

json I receive:

```
{   "data": [
  {
     "id": "MID here",
     "page": {
        "name": "Trang web b\u00e1n h\u00e0ng",
        "id": "1863210517250420"
     }
  }   ],   "paging": {
  "cursors": {
     "before": "MTg2MzIxMDUxNzI1MDQyMAZDZD",
     "after": "MTg2MzIxMDUxNzI1MDQyMAZDZD"
  }   }}
```

Now I want to change from MID to GID.

I try this

```
GET /{MID}/ids_for_pages?access_token=[page_access_token]&appsecret_proof=[appsecret_proof]
```

But I get error

```
{   "error": {
  "message": "(#230) Requires pages_messaging permission to manage the object",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 230,
  "fbtrace_id": "D+x01MWia1s"   }}
```

I've read Facebook's document in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts) but I can't find out the way to change from MID to GID.

Please help me. Thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: _“But I get error”_ – so fix the error, and see what you get then ...

Comment: Error mean I don't know how to fix it and I think it isn't the right way.
Sorry for making confused.

Comment: The error message says what you are trying to do requires a specific permission - so the first step here is of course that you go and get that permission from the user.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with ids_for_apps end point as being described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/connecting-accounts/)

Comment: Thanks you. I've got it.